# Help with DC - step down- power supply

Tags: power-supply, step-down

I've got 2 of these DC power supply units

https://www.ebay.de/itm/401176345822?hash=item5d67f93cde:g:EuQAAOSwYOxeA0mx

I work them with a 2 x 40V DC rectified transformer.

They served me well till yesterday. I tried to test an LM 3886 amp board that needs 24v DC on each side, so I tried both of them together - each one set to give 24V- without anything connected on the in and the out of the amp board. Maybe that was a mistake.

They both started behaving strangely like they didn't want to supply those 24V. Suddenly on one side I burnt one of the big capacitors on the recifier board. I unplugged everyhting changed the capacitor tested that supply only, on a different single input device, everything worked well.

Then I tested the other supply but unfortunatelly the screen was showing continuously 40V like it was taking the dc voltage from the rectifier board and bypassing the whole supply circuit.

Any idea what could I have burned and if it can be fixed?  I can't really change any of the very small ICs. The only things I can change are the 2 transistors on the heatsink. 1 IRF 5210 and 1 VF40100C.

It's not the rectifier board since I tested it with the othe supply and it's working well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Max input voltage is 55 V and with Chinese AliExpress levels of margins on product rating, you better be sure about that 40 V DC. Can you draw a block diagram or even better, a schematic of how you connected everything?

Comment: Thanks Winny. As I said before there was no problem with operating it at around 24V, but I think it drew much more since it blew one of the filter caps on one of their power supply rectifier pcbs. I know I accidentaly must gave it a lot of current or voltage.  The cap was reted 50V so ...it was more than that. I wish I knew what I've burnt on this supply board.

Comment: There is a video by Dave in the subject. Not your exact model but a very similar one where the input caps failed: https://youtu.be/Q2rvAoO-MIA

Comment: I have to admit that the video was really annoying in a way...too much speaking saying next to nothing. But ok I understand that these things may not be very sturdy, but it had served me well for two years of not intense use.  My symptom is that I can't adjust the output voltage. I dont know which IC does the job. I think I may have to try some freeze spray and maybe change the mosfets, since I can't see any burned  cap on my board.

Comment: Replace the whole unit, there's no telling how many of the devices on the board may have been fully or partially destroyed. It's still hard to see how you could have caused the problem without seeing a schematic.